# datatables and bootstrap4 - datatables goes past grid problem

Tags: bootstrap-4, datatables

I am trying to get datatables to only display within the bs4 grid but it seems to always go outside the defined grid.  Here is an example.  You can see that I have a class="container-fluid" and then a col-md-2 (left menu) and col-md-10 (main content and displays a datable).  For some reason the datatable extends past the col-md-10 to the right.  Any suggestions appreciated.

[image: Bootstrap4 layout]

I tried to condense my html as much as follows.  Here it is;

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    
    <style>
        body{margin-top:50px;}
        
        .accordion{padding-top: 5px;}
        .cardmargin{margin-bottom: 5px;}
        .panel-body { padding:5px; }
        .panel-body table tr td { padding-left: 15px }
        .panel-body .table {margin-bottom: 0px; }
        .fas { margin-right:10px; }

    </style>
    
    <link rel="icon" href="/images/favicon.ico">
    
    <!-- CSS Admin / post_index -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.24/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous"
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://development.example.com/assets/admin/post/css/post_index.css" crossorigin="anonymous">    
    
    <title>Blogs!Admin Area</title>
    
    <!-- font awesome for bs4 -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lZN37f5QGtY3VHgisS14W3ExzMWZxybE1SJSEsQp9S+oqd12jhcu+A56Ebc1zFSJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
   
    <!-- temp --> 
    <link rel="canonical" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/jumbotron/">
    
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="/assets/css/jumbotron.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

  <body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">example.com</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault" aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
          </li>
          
          <!--logged in menu -->
                    
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="dropdown01" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Welcome richard!</a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown01">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="/Profile/profile_read">Profile</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="/Login/login_delete">Logout</a>
            </div>
          </li>
          
                    
                                  <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="dropdown01" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Admin Menu</a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown01">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="/Admin/users/index">Users</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="/Login/login_delete">Logout</a>
              </div>
            </li>
                                  
        </ul>
        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
          <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <main role="main">

        <!-- show any flash messages -->
                
        
<div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="row">
     
        <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2">
            <!-- accordion sidebar here --> 
                        <!-- accordion side menu -->
            <div id="accordion" class="accordion">


              
                <!-- blogs // collapseTwo-->
                <div class="card cardmargin">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <a class="collapsed card-link" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseTwo">
                        Blogs
                    </a>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse show" data-parent="#accordion">
                        <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                                <table class="table">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <span class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></span><a href="/admin/post/post_index">Posts Index</a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <span class="fas fa-newspaper"></span><a href="/admin/post/post_create">New Post</a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <span class="fas fa-paper-plane"></span><a href="/admin/category/category_index">Categories</a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <span class="fas fa-comments"></span><a href="/admin/category/category_create">New Category</a>
                                            <span class="badge badge-dark">42</span>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            
                <!-- users // collapseThree-->
                <div class="card cardmargin">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <a class="collapsed card-link" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseThree">
                        <span class="fas fa-users"></span>Users</a>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse " data-parent="#accordion">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <table class="table">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <span class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></span><a href="/Admin/users/index">List</a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <span class="fas fa-newspaper"></span><a href="/Admin/users/user_create">New User</a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <span class="fas fa-paper-plane"></span><a href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com">Login Attempts</a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <span class="fas fa-comments"></span><a href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com">other</a>
                                            <span class="badge badge-dark">42</span>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>        </div>

        <!-- content -->
        <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-10">
            
            <!-- show errors -->
                        
            <!-- show posts intro -->
            <div class="row">
                 <h1>Posts</h1>
            </div>
            
            <!-- list posts -->
                        
            <div class="row">
                <table id="post_index"  class="table table-striped table-bordered" >
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Category</th>
                            <th>Author</th>
                            <th>Title / Post</th>
                            <th>Published?</th>
                            <th>Created</th>
                            <th>Updated</th>
                            <th></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    
                    <tbody>
                        
                                                
                        <tr>
                            
                            <!-- category -->
                            <td>
                                <a href="https://development.example.com/admin/category/index/93">
                                    Cargo                                </a>
                            </td>
                            
                            <!-- author -->
                            <td>
                                <a href="https://development.example.com/admin/post/post_read/48">
                                    Mr John                                </a>
                            </td>
                            
                            
                            <!-- title / post -->
                            <td>
                                <h6> This is the last post</h6></br>
                                Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old.&#8230;                                <a href="https://development.example.com/admin/post/post_read/242"> Read more... </a> 
                            </td>
                            
                            <!-- is_published -->
                            <td>
                                                                <a href="/admin/post/toggle_post_is_published/242" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Not Published" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to publish the post?')"> <i class="fas fa-frown"></i></a>
                                                            </td>
                            
                            <!-- post_created_at -->
                            <td>
                                2021-05-03 10:45:11                            </td>
                            
                            <!-- post_updated_at -->
                            <td>
                                2021-05-03 10:45:11                            </td>
                            
                            <!-- navigation -->
                            <td nowrap>
                                
                                <a href="https://development.example.com/admin/post/post_read/242">
                                    <span class="fas fa-book-reader"> </span> 
                                </a>
                                
                                <a href="https://development.example.com/admin/post/post_update/242">
                                    <span class="fas fa-edit"> </span> 
                                </a>
                                
                                <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Delete Post"> 
                                     <a href="https://development.example.com/admin/post/post_delete/242" onclick="return&#x20;confirm&#x28;&#x27;Do&#x20;you&#x20;want&#x20;delete&#x20;this&#x20;post&#x3F;&#x27;&#x29;"><span class="fas fa-trash-alt"></span> </a>                                </a>
                               
                               
                            </td>
                           
                        </tr>
                        
                                                
                    </tbody>
                    
                </table>
                
            </div>
        
            <!-- no posts -->
                    
        </div>  
        <!-- end content --> 
 
    </div><!--end row --> 
    
    
</div> <!-- end container -->    

        
      <hr>
    </main>

    <footer class="container">
      <p>&copy; example.com 1999-2021 || Phone:  +81-555-5555-5555      || Fax:  +81-555-5555-5555|| Email:  info@example.com      </p>
    </footer>

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
            
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.24/datatables.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.24/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>

    <!-- load additional scripts here -->
     <!-- Scripts Admin / post_index -->
                                           <script src="https://development.example.com/assets/admin/post/js/post_index.js"></script>    
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the HTML code.

Comment: @Priyank Panchal was hoping you might be able to comment please

Comment: I guess this is happening because you have put your `<table>` directly inside `<div class="row">`. Please try `<div class="row"><div class="col-12"><table>` to check if that helps.